How can one serve static html files from nginx / springboot setup (Outside springboot resources folder)
Please I would appreciate any help with the server setup that I'm working on using Nginx / SpringBoot.
The springboot is running on path
www.example.com/ (running on port 8080)
www.example.com/products/ (static html files)
But I would like to remove the static files from the spring boot application because of the large numbers of files (more than 500k)
Please what is the best way to setup the nginx configuration for this kind of requirement.
So the end result should be
www.example.com/ (served from springboot)
www.example.com/products  (served from ngnix file system)
At the moment, it works if I put the folder/files within the static section of the springboot resources.
